# QPixmap fails to load using resource

Tags: qt, qt5, qpixmap

I am trying to write a library with a custom Qt icon-text label type object in it. However the icon never displays although the widget is shown (as tested by replacing the pixmap with plain text).

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/resources.cpp
    COMMAND rcc -no-compress ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/qt/configmgr.qrc -name configmgr -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/resources.cpp
    DEPENDS src/qt/configmgr.qrc src/qt/info.png
)
...
add_library(ConfigMgr STATIC
    ...
    src/qt/section_header.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/resources.cpp
)
...
```

My configmgr.qrc:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>info.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

This produces a "resources.cpp" That looks like this:

```
static const unsigned char qt_resource_data[] = {
  0x0,0x0,0x1,0x76,
  0x89,
  0x50,0x4e,0x47,0xd,0xa,0x1a,0xa,0x0,0x0,0x0,0xd,0x49,0x48,0x44,0x52,0x0,
  ...
  0x44,0xae,0x42,0x60,0x82,
  
};

static const unsigned char qt_resource_name[] = {
  // info.png
  0x0,0x8,
  0x4,0xd2,0x59,0x47,
  0x0,0x69,
  0x0,0x6e,0x0,0x66,0x0,0x6f,0x0,0x2e,0x0,0x70,0x0,0x6e,0x0,0x67,
  
};

static const unsigned char qt_resource_struct[] = {
  // :
  0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x2,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x1,
  0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,
  // :/info.png
  0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,
  0x0,0x0,0x1,0x78,0x7d,0xe0,0x40,0x12,

};

...
```

Build output includes resources.cpp.o and that should be getting linked into the library.

My class header:

```
class SectionHeader : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        SectionHeader(const std::string &text, const std::string &info);
        virtual ~SectionHeader();

    private:
        std::string  m_info;
        QPixmap      m_icon;

};
```

My class constructor:

```
SectionHeader::SectionHeader(const std::string &text, const std::string &info)
             : m_info{info},
               m_icon(":/info.png")
{
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QLabel      *label;

    if (!m_info.empty()) {
        label = new QLabel;
        label->setPixmap(m_icon);
        layout->addWidget(label);
    }

    label = new QLabel(text.c_str());
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label->setStyleSheet("font-weight: bold; font-family: Calibre; font-size: 10pt");
    layout->addWidget(label);

    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

I have also tried calling `load()` on a QPixmap instance and it returns false.

Everything I have read, and similar code I have written before which is very similar to this, tells me that this should work. Why doesn't it?

Comment: mmm   probably you put it wrong path   `m_icon(":/info.png")` , there is no `prefix = "/"`  in `configmgr.qrc`,

Comment: try  m_icon(":info.png") maybe it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that I am trying to write **a library**.

I solved the problem by explicitly initialising the resources.

1. Find the generated CPP file for the resources. In my case it was resources.cpp.
2. Identify the name of the initialisation and cleanup functions. In my case they are:

   int qInitResources_configmgr();

   int qCleanupResources_configmgr();
3. Somewhere suitable, such as in the CPP file for your library's main class, locally declare these two functions.
4. Call the two functions in the appropriate place. E.g. main class constructor and destructor respectively.